# Django-oscar folder using virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, django-oscar

I followed the tutorial of Django-oscar: [Building your own shop](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html).

What I am trying to do is to find the original django-oscar folder; however, I don't know where it is located. I need to find this folder because I want to customize some files.

I'm using virtualenvwrapper. Does someone know how that folder can be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `virtualenv`, pip install will save the package into the virtual environment site-packages directory.

Additionally, if you use `virtualenvwrapper`, you can use [`cdsitepackages`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#cdsitepackages) command to change to site-packages directory . then you `cd oscar` from there.

In my case, `django-oscar` is located under: `/home/myname/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oscar/`

But you are not suppose to modify anything in the site-packages. Because it is managed by the third party. (You shouldn't modify django-oscar library directly, it won't be maintainable. If you do so, then you will lose the ability to update the packages automatically).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that command. My django-oscar is also located in the same path.